# password change/edit in grails acl

Tags: grails, encryption

I used grails acl security. I wanted to change or edit password of a user after logging as an admin. But when i go to the edit mode, then the password field is showing the encrypted text that was saved before as encrypted string in user table. Is there any way to decrypt the string fetched from database and show in original string form in the password field?

I did not get any straight solution to do this in grails acl.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't very good reasons to display the cleartext password. As the user or an admin, if you want to change the password then you do it like any other property. Display the old value (either as * characters since it's a password or *possibly* the hashed value if you are an admin) and then you can enter a new password. This will get hashed and stored when you update.

As long as the cleartext password satisfies the validation requirements (minimum length, special chars, etc.) then the update should work fine.

Note that passwords are generally not encrypted (which implies that they can be decrypted) but hashed. Hash algorithms are lossy - given any input the hash is typically a fixed length output, so it cannot contain all of the original data and can't be used to retrieve the original value. For passwords this is fine. To authenticate, you don't de-hash the stored value and compare to the cleartext value from the login page - you hash the login page value and compare to the stored hash. With some algorithms they'll be the same, and others (e.g. bcrypt) they'll be different but equivalent, and the algorithm will have a way to check that they're equivalent.

Comment: thanks for your answer. actually i am not showing the password while edit but retrieving in dotted mode. the problem is, it is fetching long length of dotted text(equivalent to the length of hashed value), i want to fetch dotted text which will be as same length as the original string. also it will be equivalent to the original string value otherwise it is hashing on the previous hashed string again. the only way i can see is that, i have to create another linked page from where password can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

No it is impossible to decrypt the password . It is bad idea to show password to user in edit mode. Its violet the security law. You can change a user's password but can not see it.

Comment: no actually user will not be able to see the original string because it will appear in dotted mode.

Comment: If you really need to decrypt password, write your own encryption method. But its again a bad idea to decrypt it.

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel, i'm right, you're mean in html? input type="password"?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't decrypted or d-hashed the password but added  a new page to change password for a user. in workflow i did as follows:

```
1. while creating a user, new hashed password is created
2. while edit, all other desired information are allowed to edit except password (but password is showing in hashed dotted mode for security).
3. added a new link named 'change password' in the user list beside each user
4. finally in the newly created 'changePassword' page, i have assigned another new password with hash operation for the particular user
```